# How to combine two join(()) statement into one?

Tags: python

How can I combine

```
  qty = data[8].replace(",", "")
  strike = data[0].replace('-',' ')
  print ';'.join(qty.split()),';'.join(strike.split())
```

to something like this?

```
   print ';'.join(qty.split(),strike.split())
```

Comment: `';'.join(qty.split()+strike.split())` ?

Comment: Do you want a semicolon between where the first part ends and the second part begins, or should that be a space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `itertools.chain` you can avoid creating a 3rd list, which may be useful depending on how large the first two lists are:

```
from itertools import chain

...

print ';'.join(chain(qty.split(), strike.split()))
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try this:

```
';'.join(qty.split()+strike.split())
```

ie, replace `comma(,)` with a `plus(+)` sign.